# keycloak connect to azure mariadb server

Tags: azure, mariadb, keycloak

I cannot connect keyclaok to a MariaDB server from the Azure cloud. gives an error that cannot open connect.

the connection string is connected as well as the credentials for the DB server but once I run keyclaok container it gives the following error.

```
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1322)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
keycloak_1  |   at 
org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.as.connector@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@11.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:371)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@11.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@11.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@11.0.3//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:682)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@11.0.3//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@11.0.3//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:135)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@11.0.3//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
keycloak_1  |   at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@11.0.3//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:128)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:283)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.12.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:93)
io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.3.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
keycloak_1  |   at io.undertow.s
'keycloak'
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:243)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1243)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:622)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:142)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
keycloak_1  |   at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
keycloak_1  |   ... 57 more
keycloak_1  | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown database 'keycloak'
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.authenticationHandler(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:729)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:507)
keycloak_1  |   at org.mariadb.jdbc//org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1238)
keycloak_1  |   ... 61 more
keycloak_1  | 
keycloak_1  | 21:04:14,492 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a docker-compose file ? It would be good to see it in order to help

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the stacktrace, Keycloak cannot find your database.

> Unknown database 'keycloak'

Did you set it up?

You may want to try something like this to set it up:

```sql
CREATE USER 'keycloak'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your password goes here';
CREATE DATABASE keycloak CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON keycloak.* TO 'keycloak'@'%';
```